# Spring Boot Neo4j partial update operation

Tags: java, neo4j

What is the smartest way to update nodes partially in Spring Boot application with Neo4j db.

I will get an object like this:

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "surname":"surname",
    "likes":[
        {
            "name":"football",
            "score":9
        },
        {
            "name":"golf",
            "score":6
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to use same object but with some choosen values for example:

```
{
    "surname":"otherSurname"
}
```

and achive something like this:

```
{
    "name":"name",
    "surname":"otherSurname",
    "likes":[
        {
            "name":"football",
            "score":9
        },
        {
            "name":"golf",
            "score":6
        }
    ]
}
```

Or add something to list:

```
"likes": [
        {
            "name": "basketball",
            "score": 7
        }
    ]
```

Is any way to do this?

At first I tried to delete the node and save a new one, but each time I don't get the whole object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't delete the node first and, instead, re-save the whole object, it should update new values and add/remove things that aren't in the database.

If you only want to pick and choose certain properties to save out of an object or domain class, I would write a custom query to set the updated/new values only and leave the rest.

I'm working on some examples for scenarios like this, but I don't have anything to send for demonstrating just yet.